# How to maintain state in view models between routes in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

I have a Menu and Search module. When I navigate between Menu and Search, I want to preserve my search results and Search.js state. I want modules to load via the router like a desktop application where state is maintained between module 'windows'.

App.html

```
<template>    
    <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Search.js

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {PortalData} from "./portalData";
import $ from 'jquery';

@inject(PortalData)
export class Search
{
 constructor(portalData){
    this.portalData = portalData;  
    this.criteria = "";
    this.SearchResults = [];
}

 DoSearch(startRow){    
       this.portalData.searchSevadars(criteria)
        .then(res=> this.SearchResults = res;         
    }
}
```

Menu.js

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {PortalData} from "./portalData";

@inject(PortalData)
export class Start {

    constructor(portalData){
        this.portalData = portalData;
    }

      activate(){
        return this.portalData.getApplications()
            .then(apps => this.applications = apps);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to store state in another module.
Import some class in both views, then on search store it inside a property of that class.
By default aurelia uses singleton for injected classes, so you will have a shared instance between your views.

somestate.js

```
export class SomeState {

   constructor(){
      this.data = undefined;
   }

}
```

import this module in both.
use data property to share data between modules;

Comment: Is there a way to manage state without having to bind my HTML elements against the state module e.g. value.bind=state.data.SearchInput?

Comment: Not sure what you would want to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: If I use SomeState to store state then I'd have to bind all my views to properties of SomeState. I want to avoid doing this and only bind to properties of the component's view model.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from assigning a state property to a view model property.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file called **core.js** (or something else of your choosing) in the root application folder `/src` with something like the following.  I added some extra things here to make it more realistic but you could simplify it to meet your specific needs.  My point is that this singular class could be used for a LOT of different things -- search text being just one of them.

**/src/core.js**

```
// Some example imports to support the common class
import { inject, noView } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { HttpClient, json } from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import { I18N } from 'aurelia-i18n';
import { EventAggregator } from 'aurelia-event-aggregator';

@noView // this decorator is needed since there is no core.html
@inject(EventAggregator, I18N, HttpClient)
export class Core {
  value1 = "Test data 1";
  value2 = "Test data 2";
  constructor(eventAggregator, i18n, httpClient) {
    // store local handles
    this.eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.httpClient = httpClient;

    // search info
    this.SearchResults = [];
  }

  myCustomFunction() {
    // some code here, available to any component that has core.js injected
  }
}
```

Then, import and inject core.js into each of your other components, like this:

**search.js**

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {PortalData} from "./portalData";
import {Core} from "core";
import $ from 'jquery';

@inject(PortalData, Core)
export class Search
{
 constructor(portalData, core){
    this.portalData = portalData;
    this.core = core;
    this.criteria = "";
}

 DoSearch(startRow){    
       this.portalData.searchSevadars(criteria)
        .then(res=> this.core.SearchResults = res;         
    }
}
```